# How To Create Wordpress Dashboard Item

Tags: admin, dashboard

I have just started in building Wordpress sites as a side-project. Can anyone please help me with something that I cannot figure out? How do I create a "section" like Case Studies in the below screenshot?

[image]

The "case studies" section (I don't know if I should call it like this) operates just like a simple blog section, which I will use with Elementor for pages that will act like indexes. Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those are custom post types

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do in your case - is to create a custom post type. Please read about post types in WordPress here https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/

You can use a plugin to create Case Studies post type https://uk.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/